# PHP - Get the md5 of remote file?

Tags: php, ftp, md5

Is it possible to get the md5 of a file on a remote server? If so how?

Answer (score 15):

how about `md5_file("http://remotelocation/file")`

Comment: i didnt know about this if this command is a valid in php then +1

Comment: Most filesystem functions apply to streams, including HTTP.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will transfer the whole content of the remote file to your server. May be feasible, may be not.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible without downloading it, or the remote server providing the information (web service, HTML page, etc.)

You can use `md5(file_get_contents("http://remotelocation/file"))` to download the file and calculate the md5 hash if your PHP installation is configured to open remote streams. But that will download the complete file.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not the md5 of the actual file, it's the md5 of the actual output.

Comment: If you are talking about a server-side script such as a `.php` file, you cannot get the MD5 stamp of it, or the source code inside it in general, via HTTP. That would be a security disaster if you could! You would have to use the appropriate connection you use to access the source on the server, eg. [S]FTP.

Answer (score 3):

Well depends what you mean. There are two ways:

1. You connect to the remote server and calculate the hash there (like ssh to the server).
2. Get (download) the file and compute the hash.

Obviously to calculate the hash of a file you have to read the contents of the file.

Comment: I'm not very good with ssh. Is there an example you could provide for example 1? Like.. $a = exec('some shell stuff to return the file info');

Comment: @John if you have ssh access to the other server maybe it's easier to place a PHP file there to calculate the MD5 over a GET request.