# PHP - Hash contents of uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, hash

I would like to hash the contents of an uploaded file in MD5. The file will not be saved locally so it only exists in a tmp directory.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. MD5 is fine. It's just for debugging right now.

Comment: think there is `md5_file()`? See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304081/php-get-the-md5-of-remote-file) Also you may want to use a stronger hash like SHA that will have less possibilities of collisions.

Comment: See the second answer here. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770900/is-md5-less-secure-than-sha-et-al-in-a-practical-sense

Comment: This is just for debugging. Only up to 3 files will be stored so I don't need to worry about collisions. I different hashing function will be used in the final, I just need to make sure the rest of it works.

Comment: Just as a note, hashing a file in md5 does not provide storage ability - its use is more for file verification. You cannot 'decode' the md5 hash to create a usable file.

Comment: 65Fbef05, Thank you but I understand how hashing functions work :]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `md5_file()` or `sha1_file()` function. For example, if your post variable is `filevar`:

```
$myhash = md5_file($_FILES['filevar']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: I'm late :) +1 for exactly same answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`md5_file()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php), even on your temporary file.

Answer (score 2):

`MD5()` for string and `md5_file()` for files