# php script that gives md5 of a online file

Tags: php, md5, checksum

hi i'm looking for a script that gives me the md5 of a file by link 
i have all ready a script that gives the md5 of the files that are in the folder but now i wanna add a script where you paste the link to the file and it prints out the md5
if some one knows how to make this plz let me know

code that i have :

```
<?php
$cwd = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cwd = substr($cwd, 0, strrpos($cwd, '/' + 1));

function paintUndersideOfFox($c) {
global $cwd;
echo('<ul class="dirlist">');
$d = opendir($c);
while($f = readdir($d)) {
  if(strpos($f, '.') === 0) continue;
  $ff = $c . '/' . $f;
  echo 'MD5 file hash of ' . $ff . ': ' . md5_file($ff);
  echo('<li><a href="' . $cwd . $ff . '">' . $ff . '</a></li><br />');
  if(is_dir($ff)) paintUndersideOfFox($ff);
 }
 echo('</ul>');
}

paintUndersideOfFox('.');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most filesystem functions apply to streams, including HTTP. Did you try this

```
md5_file("http://remotelocation/file")
```

Comment: yeah i know but it must be like this, input form (here comes the url) button (to start calculating) script get the file  gets the md5 after that removes file from server

Comment: what is the point in getting the file to your filesystem if you are anyways deleting it again after calculating the md5 of the file

Comment: just a sugestion if it can calculate the md5 without downloading fine for me

Comment: what is the issue then. You have the url to the file from the form, just use it in the way I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading files can be done via `file_get_contents()` or more securely with CURL

Comment: one thing to note is, that some webhosting providers block ability of file_get_contents() to download remote files, curl would work OK, though

Comment: well there are many ways, actually the other suggested answer makes sense: md5_file("http://urlfromtheform.com/file");
optionally:
md5(file_get_contents('http://urlfromtheform.com/file'));

Comment: If for some reason you cannot use these methods (e.g. your hosting provider blocks this functionality), you may refer to this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl -> Btw before asking you should have tried searching SO for similar answers, there are many of them... For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304081/php-get-the-md5-of-remote-file

Comment: wath i need is a pre made script